# replace file with new one with timestamp

Tags: c#

I have a file in a directory:

```
Path.Combine(dir1, "participants.txt")
```

---

I want to check if `participants.txt` exists in `dir1`. And if it does copy it to a new file named `participants[timestamp].txt`. And replace the old one with the information `lines`.

---

### I have tried this:

```
if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir1, "participants.txt")))
{
    File.Copy("participants.txt", "participants" + Stopwatch.GetTimestamp().ToString() + ".txt");
    File.WriteAllLines("participants.txt", lines);
}
```

But this isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the full path in your filename specifiers:

```
String source = Path.Combine(dir1, "participants.txt");
if (File.Exists(source)) {
    File.Copy(source, Path.Combine(dir1, "participants" + Stopwatch.GetTimestamp().ToString() + ".txt"));
    File.WriteAllLines(source, lines);
}
```